# Add row to HTML table with Laravel Livewire - Issue

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade, laravel-livewire

Firstly I'm new to Laravel and this is my first post. Please forgive me if I'm doing things wrong.

I have an HTML table, which is a Livewire component. In this HTML table, each row has a dropdown box and some text fields. This is for a timesheet application. The dropdown is the job and there are 7 text boxes, for each day of the week for the hours to be entered.

I have tried to include an Add button, I want this to add a new row at the end of the HTML table.

The issue I'm getting is when I click on Add, it will append the row, however, my dropdown is not shown, UNTIL I refresh the page, then it appears as it should.

The way I currently have my program is that when a user clicks on add, it will create a new record in my Entries table, with the timesheet ID included, and the rest of the values as null. Is there another way of temporarily storing the lines the user creates, then commit to the database? Is there a way to refresh my table so that it displays the new line correctly?

Please let me know if you need further details or a better explanation of my issue.

My code is as follows:

Controllers\Livewire\ShowTimesheet.php

```
...
public function mount($entries)
   {
       $this->entries = $entries;
   }

    public function render()
    {
        return view(‘livewire.show-timesheet');
    }

    public function add($i)
    {
        $entries_new = new Entries;
        $entries_new->timesheet_id = $i;
        $entries_new->save();

        $new = array(
            'id'=>$entries_new->id,
            'timesheet_id'=>$i,
            'job_id'=>null,
            'worktype_id'=>null,
            'hours_sun'=>null,
            'hours_mon'=>null,
            'hours_tue'=>null,
            'hours_wed'=>null,
            'hours_thu'=>null,
            'hours_fri'=>null,
            'hours_sat'=>null,
        );
        $this->entries[] = $new;
    }
...
```

Layouts\livewire\show-timesheet.blade

```
...
@foreach($timesheet as $sheet)
...
<div wire:click="add({{$sheet['id']}})" class='cursor-pointer'>
...
 @endforeach
...
```

Comment: Have a watch of [this YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iuIEqOcQi6g).

Comment: Amazing! Thank you so much!